How can we set the encoding of flyway files in a Quarkus backend?
In our maven project we have updated our dependencies (Quarkus 3.10.0, with flyway-core 9.22.3). Now, when we run the project, we run into the following error that we did not get before:
org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayTeamsUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Teams Edition upgrade required: detectEncoding is not supported by Flyway Community Edition
Try Flyway Teams Edition for free: https://rd.gt/2VzHpkY
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration.setDetectEncoding(ClassicConfiguration.java:815)
    at org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration.detectEncoding(FluentConfiguration.java:350)
    at io.quarkus.flyway.runtime.FlywayCreator.createFlyway(FlywayCreator.java:146)
    at io.quarkus.flyway.runtime.FlywayContainerProducer.createFlyway(FlywayContainerProducer.java:53)

However, I do not think we are actively using this encoding feature, and it is set automatically by Quarkus. Is there anyway we can set the encoding ourselves, such that quarkus does not need to use setDetectEncoding?
I tried adding &characterEncoding=UTF-8 to our quarkus.datasource url, and I tried to directly set quarkus.flyway.encoding=UTF-8, but that does not resolve the error.
